# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource (persistance errors)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm following this tutorial to set up the dependencies for my maven project in eclipse. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnTTbu_6WH8&index=10&list=PLHqN89yRGMyAcwWcSWk59_S_-BQVn3Rrb 
When I try to launch the server I get the following console error stack. I'm pretty comfortable with regular Java but this is the first time I'm doing Java EE or maven. I know  the errors are caused missing classes but I'm not sure how to fix that since I copied their links from the tutorial and they seem to work there. If there is any file you need to see that I missed out please let me know.

```html
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.63
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 30 2015 08:08:33 UTC
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.63.0
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_25-b18
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Albert\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Albert\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Albert\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;C:\Users\Albert\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\Users\Albert\Downloads\eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1792 ms
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.63
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:35 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [2,205] milliseconds.
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
04:15:44,109 ERROR ContextLoader:308 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/datasource-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] class or package not found
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5017)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5531)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] class or package not found
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1401)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1184)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1048)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:693)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:268)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
 ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.j2eeapp.domain.UserEntity
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1722)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1573)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.classForName(Ejb3Configuration.java:1318)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1390)
 ... 29 more
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/datasource-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] class or package not found
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5017)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5531)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] class or package not found
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1401)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1184)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1048)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:693)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:268)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
 ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.j2eeapp.domain.UserEntity
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1722)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1573)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.classForName(Ejb3Configuration.java:1318)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1390)
 ... 29 more

Aug 13, 2015 4:15:44 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.10 (-SNAPSHOT 20120625-1354) for context '/jee'
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:44 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:46 AM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 3.4
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/jee] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:46 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/jee] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
Aug 13, 2015 4:15:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 13620 ms
```

Here is my datasource-config.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd         
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
                        
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:datasource.properties" />
                        
        <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
                <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
                <property name="URL" value="${url}" />
                <property name="user" value="${user}" />
                <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        </bean>                 
        
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
                <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
                        </bean>
                </property>
                
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>
        
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>
        
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

Application-context.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
        
        <import resource="datasource-config.xml" />
        <import resource="webflow-config.xml" />        
        <import resource="security-config.xml" />
        
       
        
</beans>
```

Web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="htpp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://www.java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://www.java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 version="2.5">
 
 <display-name>j2app</display-name>
 
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 
 <context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        
        <context-param>
                <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
                <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        
        <context-param>
                <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>
        
        <context-param>
                <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
                <param-value>1</param-value>
        </context-param>
        
        <listener>
                <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        
        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        
        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        
        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                        <param-value></param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        
        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        
        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        
        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        
        <filter>
                <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
                <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        </filter>
        
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <!-- Spring security filters -->
    <filter>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
        
        <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
        
 
</web-app>
```

and finally pom file

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>j2app</groupId>
  <artifactId>j2app</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>j2appp</name>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
                <id>prime-repo</id>
                <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
                <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
  </repositories>
  
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>20030825.184428</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Spring for a while but I remember there were a lot of MAven dependencies to specify (`spring-context`, etc.) 
Besides, it seems like you're mixing different versions of Spring in your pom.xml: `2.3.1.RELEASE`, `3.0.5.RELEASE` and `3.1.1.RELEASE`. IIRC, you should have the same versions for all your Spring modules.

Comment: Except spring security, it follows different version timeline :)

Comment: Right, I was too quick at picking module versions ;-)

Comment: any other suggestions guys?

Comment: Have you checked that you have all the required Spring core modules with the same versions ?

Comment: How would I check that